# How to define `d.ts` for common js module

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have developers who write common js modules such as:

```js
module.exports = {
    countries: function() {
        return ['Germany'];
    }
};
```

Where we expect them to provide certain keys on the exported object, with certain function declarations.

How can I make some type intellisense to ease their work? One of the requirements is not have any imports in this javascript file.